# In actionscript, how do I write keyboard handler without typing ascii codes in my code?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am writing a keyboard event handler in actionscript.  I would like to trace something when the letter "d" is pressed.

```
private static const THE_LETTER_D:int = 100;
private function onKeyUp(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
   if (evt.keyCode == THE_LETTER_D )
   {
      trace('Someone pressed the letter d');
   }
}
```

Is there a way I can do this without defining THE_LETTER_D?  I tried to do int('d') but that does not work, and I am not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private function onKeyUp(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (evt.charCode == 'd'.charCodeAt(0) )
    {
        trace('Someone pressed the letter d');
    }
}
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

The [flash.ui.Keyboard](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/ui/Keyboard.html) component holds a couple of constants that represents keyboard characters.

```
private function onKeyUp(evt:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (evt.charCode == Keyboard.D)
    {
        trace('Someone pressed the letter D');
    }
}
```